# What kanji is used for ~まに?

Tags: kanji

Consider

> 先生のいない**まに**、すばやくホワイトボードを消してしまった。
>
> I erased the white board quickly while the teacher wasn't there.

According to [IMABI](https://www.imabi.net/whileiiuchi.htm):

> ～まに is used to show that one does something when a chance arises and the time until that chance is lost. Thus, it has interchangeability with ～あいだに. It just has the added sense of taking advantage.

**Question:** Is there a Kanji associated with this usage of ま? Is it just 間 (i.e. same as あいだ)?

Comment: Yes. まに means 間に

Comment: FYI a common expression [鬼の居ぬ間に洗濯](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/srch/all/%E9%AC%BC%E3%81%AE%E5%B1%85%E3%81%AC%E9%96%93%E3%81%AB%E6%B4%97%E6%BF%AF/m1u/).

Answer (score 2):

Echoing the comment of @Jimmy Yang: まに means 間に.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/36059)

Comment: @broccolifacemask This is clearly an answer to the original question (and a correct one, too). There is no rule against answering your own question (although there is a guideline not to post an answer in the comment section even if it's short).